# RollupError: Could not resolve "./components/Header.jsx" from "src/App.jsx"

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, vite, vercel

Buen dia! Estuve tratando de implementar una app para un curso que estoy haciendo. La habia podido implemenetar en su momento con Vercel. Me pidieron que hicera algunos cambios y ahora cuando trato de hacer el deploy me dale este error de build en la terminal de Vercel:

```
´´´ 
RollupError: Could not resolve "./components/Header.jsx" from "src/App.jsx" 
´´´
```

El problema parece venir de App.jx o de Header.jsx, asi se ven estos dos componentes:

App:

```
´´´

    //APP.JSX
    
    import React from "react";
    import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
    import Header from './components/Header.jsx';
    import CharacterList from "./components/CharacterList.jsx";
    import ComicDetail from "./components/ComicDetail.jsx";
    import Favorites from "./components/Favorites.jsx";
    import Footer from "./components/Footer.jsx";
    
    const App = () => {
      
      return (
        <>
          <Header/>
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/*" element={<CharacterList />} />
              <Route path="/comics/:comic" element={<ComicDetail />} />
              <Route path="/favorites" element={<Favorites />} />
            </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;

´´´
```

Header:

```
´´´

    //HEADER.JSX
    
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { StyledHeader, ImageContainer, Form, SearchInput, StyledLink, StarOutlineIcon, StarFillIcon } from '../styles/componentStyles';
    import { useMarvelContext } from '../context/MarvelContext';
    import useMarvelSearch from '../hooks/useMarvelSearch';
    
    const Header = () => {
      const { favorites } = useMarvelContext();
      const { search, inputValue, handleInputChange, setRandomCharacter } = useMarvelSearch();
    
      useEffect(()=> {
        setRandomCharacter()
      }, [])
    
      const handleSearch = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        search(inputValue)
      }
    
      return (
        <StyledHeader>
          <ImageContainer>
            <a href="https://www.marvel.com/" target='_blank'>
              <img src="./src/assets/Marvel_Logo.png" alt="Marvel Logo" />
            </a>
          </ImageContainer>
    
          <Form onSubmit={handleSearch} >
            <SearchInput type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputChange}placeholder="Search character..." />
          </Form>
    
          <StyledLink to="/favorites">
            {
              favorites.length === 0 ?
              <StarOutlineIcon />
              : 
              <StarFillIcon />
            }
          </StyledLink>
        </StyledHeader>
      );
    }
    
    export default Header;

´´´
```

El proyecto se hizo con VITE+React. No se si necesiten más contexto para poder ayudarme, busque por todos lados y no encuentro una solucion!

Comment: Revisa el working directory, dentro de `src` verifica que el folder `components` sigue ahí

Comment: Esta todo en su lugar, la aplicacion corre bien en dev. El error ocurre cuando vercel trata de hacer el build y se rompe en esa linea.